# How does HTTP max-age works and how to expire cache after some time?

Tags: php, http, http-headers, cache-control

I manage the HTTP caching in my applications. And it's not working as I think it should. Let's get to an actual example:

With the first serve of my PHP page I serve the following HTTP headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 12 Dec 2016 16:39:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 1980 19:53:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=60, pre-check=60
Last-Modified: Mon, 12 Dec 2016 15:57:25 GMT
Etag: "a2883c859ce5c8153d65a4e904c40a79"
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 326
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

My application manage the validation of Etags and send 304 if nothing has changed and when you refresh the page in the browser (F5) you get (if nothing has changed server side):

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Mon, 12 Dec 2016 16:43:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
```

Since I serve `Cache-Control: private` with `max-age=60` I would expect that after one minute the cache will be considered obsolete by the browser and it will request a fresh copy (equivalent of a Ctrl+F5 reload) but instead the cache is still valid several days after it's `max-age`.

Do I misunderstood these HTTP mechanism? Do I send something wrong or maybe miss something?

Comment: @Dagon Yes I know but in my example after 1 minute don't a F5 would request a fresh copy (like Ctrl+F5)? At the moment 3 days after a F5 still answer with a 304 like if the cache is still walid...

Comment: it might not be the browser cache, there can be other caches between server and client, such as the ISP. And none are obliged to follow the "rules"

Comment: Why bother downloading a fresh copy of the current one you have can be revalidated? That's the whole point of 304s to save you that download of the resource hadn't changed and you still have a cached copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a cached response is within the max-age, then it is considered *fresh*.

If it exceeds the max-age, then it is considered *stale*.

If a browser needs a resource and it has a fresh copy in the cache, then it will use that without checking back with the server.

If the browser has a stale copy then it will validate that against the server (in this case, using Etags) to see if it needs a new copy of it the cached copy is still OK.

Comment: Ohh I see I need to validate this with some tests and get back to you with my findings!

Comment: OK so in my present example it seems the browser always validate Etags with the browser even when it's cache is < 60 secs. Do you see something in my headers that might trigger this? I can setup a live demo if it helps.

Comment: If you do an F5 refresh the. It will always validate by checking with server. See my answer here for more info (and a handy tip/warning about gzip+etags - though I see you are not using this in above example): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926999/enable-caching-of-css-and-js-files-in-apache/33927289

Comment: Ohh I see, How would I test that the cache item is stale?

Comment: Go to a different page. Click a link that takes you to the page you want to test the caching for.

Comment: Ohh I see.. I implemented that system so long ago that I forgot how browsers work! Everything works as expected, thanks!