# ASP NET.5 versioning ES6 module in razor pages

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, es6-modules

When importing scripts in razor files, you could version them in this simple way:

```
<script src="~/lib/myscript.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

How can I do an equivalent thing inside the module script:

```
<script type="module">
    import * as mynamespace from '/lib/myscript.js';
    ...
</script>
```

Does exists something that returns the string appended by the system?

```
import * as mynamespace from '/lib/myscript.js?version='@HTML.GetAspAppendVersionValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70005851/3370431). Basically, you simulate `asp-append-version` by adding version numbers to your file names (e.g. `MyScript.v1.js`) then rename the file when you change it and let Visual Studio update all the file references for you.